# how to update user profile using API (PUT) in cs-cart

Tags: cs-cart

`http://localhost/multivendor_v4.11.5/api/users?email=dev@gmail.com&user_type=C&company_id=0&status=A&firstname=dev&lastname=dev&company=&company_name=no&password1=12345678&password2=12345678&phone=4444444999&user_id=20&profile_id=21`

**I tried update user profile using this URL in Postman but it is not working.
I need to pass some more parameter to run this request?**

Comment: you did not add the PORT in your request, maybe that's the problem? check for which  PORT is your server running on and add it to and of the localhost. Example: localhost:8080.

Comment: before in body I was passing data in form-data. It was wrong format. Now I tried with raw. Its working now

Comment: try to pass data as raw json as request body